# wget command for downloading a video after the request authentification on allocine

Tags: bash, sh

I don't understand how and which fields of the login page https://salles.allocine.fr that i must keep and traduce in my wget command line

it's for a bash script that will download the trailer to show for a playlist given to it

I tried a command line like this:

```
wget --post-data="Username=MyUserId&Password=MyPass" --keep-session-cookies --save-cookies cookies.txt "https://salles.allocine.fr/Account/LogOn?ReturnUrl=%2fVideoDownloads%2fDownloadVideo%2f19583540%0A";

wget -S -U "Mozilla/5.0" --keep-session-cookies --load-cookies cookies.txt -P $thePath/ -O testDownloadjpg.mp4 "https://salles.allocine.fr/VideoDownloads/DownloadVideo/19583540"
```

I tried ( but without really understanding ) the parameter `--secure-protocol=auto`

I although tried the parameter  `--http-user=MyUserId --http-password=MyPass`  but i think it is for sites that use a post form method.

My  wget --post-data="Username=MyUserId&Password=MyPass" --keep-session-cookies --save-cookies cookies.txt "https://salles.allocine.fr/Account/LogOn?ReturnUrl=%2fVideoDownloads%2fDownloadVideo%2f19583540%0A"
makes a file called `LogOn?ReturnUrl=%2fVideoDownloads%2fDownloadVideo%2f19583540.1`
In my opinion, i do think that this command shoudn't make a file.
I have successfully downloaded my video with the use of a Mozilla plugin https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/cliget/ that gave the wget command. Unfortunately this way can't be longer an automatic method.
In fact, on  my other pc i must use the plugin again.
I give this to help you to give me an eventual answer :)

```
wget --header 'Host: salles.allocine.fr' --user-agent 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux i686; rv:67.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/67.0' --header 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8' --header 'Accept-Language: fr,fr-FR;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3' --header 'Cookie: _ga=GA1.2.1953313605.1547124307; geolevel1=73072; geolevel2=73072; geolevel3=73072; geocode=115755; cto_lwid=74252535-e0d9-4085-a8a9-4dc53e62fcdd; cto_idcpy=ec388dde-ba94-4e78-a629-9bd319ef98a6; _fbp=fb.1.1555088532774.784786208; country_code=FR; geolevel4=73072; geolevel5=73072; geolevel6=73072; geolevel7=73072; geolevel8=73072; geolevel9=73072; geolevel10=73072; geolevel11=73072; geolevel12=73072; geolevel13=83093; geolevel14=83165; nugg=g%3D1%26o%3D2%26i%3D4%26f%3D4%26a%3D3%26l%3D1%26s%3D3%26k%3D2%26m%3D1%26h%3D1%26e%3D4%26fa%3D4%26pc%3D4%26ce%3D4%26ch%3D4%26do%3D4%26da%3D4%26ar%3D4%26em%3D4%26tr%3D4%26ci%3D2%26le%3D0%26ag%3D0%26pf%3D0%26hy%3D0%26uh%3D1%26gp%3D1%26kr%3D1%26tk%3D1%26we%3D1%26rm%3D0%26mi%3D0%26wn%3D1%26sw%3D0%26bi%3D0%26frq%3D1%26cb%3D0%26sa%3D0%26ls%3D1%26he%3D1%26ym%3D0%26lh%3D1%26hm%3D0%26gm%3D0%26ht%3D1%26bc%3D0%26fs%3D0%26cg%3D0%26ds%3D0%26hs%3D1%26yc%3D0%26tg%3D1%26cf%3D1%26dd%3D7%26db%3D5%26ds%3D3%26ex%3D4%26eb%3D6%26ad%3D3%26sb%3D6%26on%3D3%26cke%3D0%26mx%3D0%26asc%3D3%26bxb%3D0%26pdr%3D0%26cos%3D0%26hm_eat%3D1%26hm_afd%3D1%26hm_acimp%3D0%26hm_pmg%3D0%26hm_penv%3D1%26hm_fasl%3D0; _gid=GA1.2.357818189.1559383490; CurrentLanguage=fr; ASP.NET_SessionId=h5gftt5bebgkgakoksnd5moz; .ASPXAUTH=9C3826A4398574BFC23C7D40805AE2EB76DF08F18F3C2DA0C2C96EA806550F5AD9E1376F6C14EB474F4CF764DD02CA835A504A3F4ADFFAE49CDE2114711D8292CB23AF02A7581946CFFA216B9C63FB61BB6F57607835A166ED5EC938096A9C1A92BEC90738E86CF4B01D2D4174F83BCD75A185D1A76C33194D7CF847FC3BDE5C; login=P1001; cUser=168; crypUser=4B5154; CurrentCinema=767' --header 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1' 'https://salles.allocine.fr/VideoDownloads/DownloadVideo/19582665'  -P $thePath/ -O testDownloadjpg.mp4
```

Comment: FWIW, [youtube-dl](https://youtube-dl.org/) appears to support Allocine.

Comment: Thanks! So i tied it :  youtube-dl -u MyId -p pass https://salles.allocine.fr/VideoDownloads/DownloadVideo/19583540  and had this error:  
[generic] 19583540: Requesting header
WARNING: Could not send HEAD request to https://salles.allocine.fr/VideoDownloads/DownloadVideo/19583540: <urlopen error [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution>
[generic] 19583540: Downloading webpage
ERROR: Unable to download webpage: <urlopen error [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution> (caused by URLError(gaierror(-3, 'Temporary failure in name resolution'),))

Comment: do `host salles.allocine.fr` and `ping salles.allocine.fr` work?